# Tenant ID cookie value cannot be read when publishing API on IIS

Tags: .net, session, iis, cookies, aspnetboilerplate

I am using the Angular and aspnetboilerplate template in a project. When I change the tenant on the login screen it validates that the tenant exists, adds the cookie **Abp.TenantId** then reloads the page. However, after the reload it still shows me that no tenant has been chosen and when I login I do so as host instead of tenant.

The problem is that is working perfectly fine when I am serving locally and even when publishing on a server. But when I published it on a server with cloudflare SSL it stopped working, I cannot understand how switching from HTTP to HTTPS can cause such an issue. I checked the request & response headers but found nothing that would help.

Request Headers:

```
:authority: apicompany.com
:method: GET
:path: /api/services/app/Session/GetCurrentLoginInformations
:scheme: https
accept: text/plain
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9
cache-control: no-cache
expires: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT
origin: https://admincompany.com
pragma: no-cache
referer: https://admincompany.com/
sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="106", "Google Chrome";v="106", "Not;A=Brand";v="99"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
sec-fetch-dest: empty
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-site: same-site
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest
```

Response Headers:

```
access-control-allow-credentials: true
access-control-allow-origin: https://admincompany.com
alt-svc: h3=":443"; ma=86400, h3-29=":443"; ma=86400
cf-cache-status: DYNAMIC
cf-ray: 762b1f89d89775bf-LHR
content-encoding: br
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
date: Mon, 31 Oct 2022 08:46:57 GMT
nel: {"success_fraction":0,"report_to":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}
report-to: {"endpoints":[{"url":"https:\/\/a.nel.cloudflare.com\/report\/v3?s=..."}],"group":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}
server: cloudflare
vary: Origin
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
```

Comment: Are you using NginX?

Comment: No, I am not, but I don't see how using it might help

Comment: "When you publish it on a server using cloudflare SSL, it stops working". What error are you getting? Please post detailed error message.

Comment: I don't get any error message, the cookie is being saved and also sent to the server. I am assuming it is not being read by the API as it doesn't change to the Tenant and stays as host

Comment: I suggest that you can post your question in the Cloudflare community, where there will be more professional guidance for your issue and you can ask for help troubleshooting Cloudflare SSL errors. https://community.cloudflare.com/